# ReactJS error: TypeError: this.state.data is undefined

Tags: reactjs

Learning ReactJS practically so I've made an "app" that will load jokes async with Fetch request and load them on the page.

## ReactCode

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { 
           data : [],
        }
     }
    componentDidMount(){
     this.postdata()
    }

    postdata(){
        var initial_data = {'id': 1, 'model-name': 'Joke'}
        var self = this;
            fetch("\start-jokes\/", {
            body: JSON.stringify(initial_data),
            cache: 'no-cache', 
            credentials: 'same-origin', 
            headers: {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
            'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors', 
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            })
            .then(response => response.json()).then((json) => {
              self.setState({ data : json.data }) // which ever the key hold the data 
            })
    }

    render(){
       return( 
            <div>
            {this.state.data.length == 0 && 
               <div> No options available.</div>
            }
            {this.state.data.length > 0 && 
              <div className="container" id="jokes">
                   {this.state.data.map(function(item,i){
                          return(
                                <div key={i} className="card col-md-7">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                {item}   // here you are getting object in item. Get the key from the object like item.name
                                </div>
                                </div>
                      )
                   })}
               </div>
            }
          </div>
         )
    }
}
// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

it however logs this error message in the console.

```
TypeError: this.state.data is undefined
```

`this.state.data` is referenced twice in `render` and `data` is declared in the `constructor`.

Possible cause is though it's not getting it from the constructor therefore failing.

## Update

Thanks to the suggestion I have tried logging `console.log(json.data)` and as predicted got back `undefined` however I'm sure there's data sent back correctly just that it comes back as an `Object` and might need a different way to access the data.

Console log `json` response returns this `Object { status: "ok", jokes: Array[10], ref-id: 11 }`

Comment: please verify that `json.data` in your response actually contains data or not

Comment: try console logging `json.data` and see what you are getting

Comment: bind this function in the constructor --> postdata()

Comment: must be getting rusty... I should have used `json['jokes']` instead of `json.data`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `json.data` you are assigning here:

```
.then(response => response.json()).then((json) => {
  self.setState({ data : json.data }) // which ever the key hold the data 
})
```

is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
renderList = () => {
    if (this.state.data){
        return this.state.data.map(function(item,i){
                return(
                    <div key={i} className="card col-md-7">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            {item}
                        </div>
                    </div>
            )
        })
    }
}

render(){
        let html = this.state.data?(
            <div className="container" id="jokes">
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        ) : (<div> No options available.</div>) 
       return( 
            <div>
                {html}
            </div>
         )
    }
```

Try refactoring your code a little bit.
Always do a null check before doing rendering operation. 
Always use Arrow functions otherwise you will have to bind the functions manually in the constructor of the class.

Hope this helps.